# Create React app error when starting a project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I successfully installed React:

```
 npm install -g create-react-app
```

but then I'm trying to initialize a project with this line of code:

```
create-react-app serviceApp
```

I keep getting this error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...^2.2.4","should":"^7.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andaeiii\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-04T00_45_19_195Z-debug.log
```

I've tried uninstalling node and npm, but to no avail.

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` and try again

Comment: i have done that over and over, even reinstalled npm, over and over.but still

Comment: already faced same error but `npm cache clean` fixed it for me, but i can see you on windows, try running terminal as admin to clean cache, if wont work u can also try  `%AppData%/npm-cache` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html then delete all files and run `npm install`